# The value of $k$ for which the point $(\alpha,\arcsin \alpha)(\alpha>0)$ lies inside the triangle formed by $x+y=k$ with the coordinate axes is-

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

The value of $k$ for which the point $(\alpha,\arcsin \alpha)(\alpha>0)$ lies inside the triangle formed by $x+y=k$ with the coordinate axes is-

---

As the point $(\alpha,\arcsin \alpha)(\alpha>0)$ lies inside the triangle formed by $x+y=k$ with the coordinate axes.So $\alpha+\arcsin \alpha<k,\alpha>0$
Now i cannot solve this.The answer given is $k\in(1+\frac{\pi}{2},\infty)$

Answer (score 3):

Function $\arcsin\alpha$ is defined only for $-1\le\alpha\le1$, but in this case we are told that $\alpha>0$, hence we conclude that $0<\alpha\le1$. In this range $\arcsin\alpha$ is increasing and varies from $\arcsin0=0$ and $\arcsin1=\pi/2$:
$$
0<\arcsin\alpha\le{\pi\over2}.
$$
You can see below, in red, the graph of $y=\arcsin x$ for $0<x\le1$. Point $P$ has coordinates $(1,\pi/2)$ and the line passing through it has then equation $x+y=1+\pi/2$. The value $k=1+\pi/2$ is then the lowest allowing all the graph to be contained inside the triangle formed by line $x+y=k$ with the coordinate axes.

[image]